# Loop through each element from third to last of active record object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have active record object of array.

```
@obj = User.post
```

Now I want to loop through @obj from third element to last. I want something like below

```
@obj.third-to-last.each do 
#output here
end
```

I can do this using a counter and if else condition. I want know if there is any better and simple way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`Array#drop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-drop) method to drop the first two elements of `@obj`:

```
@obj.drop(2).each do |obj|
  # whatever...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do using method [`ary[range]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) :

```
@obj[2..-1].each do |el| 
   # your code here
end
```